# R error in fPortfolio package: could not find function "tclVar"

Tags: r, compiler-errors, tcltk, tcltk2

I load fPortfolio with a pre-installed data frame attached:

```r
library(fPortfolio)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

data("edhec")

rets <- edhec

# compute the tangency portfolio
tp <- tangencyPortfolio(as.timeSeries(edhec))

frontier <- portfolioFrontier(as.timeSeries(edhec))
#plot(frontier) # Plots frontier, don't need this

# The problem is when I run this code:
weightsSlider(object = frontier, control = list())
```

When I run the last line, `weightsSlider` I get an Error:

```
Error in tclVar(starts[i]) : could not find function "tclVar"
```

A separate window opens up that says 'window slider'.

If I run:

```r
capabilities()["tclVar"]
```

I get the error:

```
<NA> 
 NA
```

And when I run:

```r
tcltk::tclVar
```

I get the error:

```r
function (init = "") 
{
    n <- .TkRoot$env$TclVarCount <- .TkRoot$env$TclVarCount + 
        1L
    name <- paste0("::RTcl", n)
    l <- list(env = new.env())
    assign(name, NULL, envir = l$env)
    reg.finalizer(l$env, function(env) tcl("unset", names(env)))
    class(l) <- "tclVar"
    tclvalue(l) <- init
    l
}
<bytecode: 0x000001b271b9ddd0>
<environment: namespace:tcltk>
```

I installed both the `tcl` and the `tcltk2` packages.

---

[fPortfolio rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fPortfolio/versions/280.73/topics/weightsSlider)

[fPortfolio github](https://github.com/cran/fPortfolio/blob/1f8c3465d08b6ba34dc2e68a50ef1bcef95437f8/man/weights-Slider.Rd)